# UITableViewからperformSegueWithIdentifierを行うとUITableVIewがスクロールする？

Tags: swift, ios8, uitableview

曖昧な質問になってしまうのですが、もし、同様の状況、あるいは解決策等をご存知であれば、ご教示いただければと思います。

Swift で、UITableView(UITableViewController でも)で、dynamic prototypes でテーブルビューを作成します。関係ないかもしれませんが、Sytle は Grouped です。

StroyBoard でカスタム cell を作成し、その cell から他のUIViewController(UITableViewController) に segue を接続し、Accessory Action として、show(push) segue を選択します。

そこで、もとの UITableView で `tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` メソッドで、 performSegueWithIdentifier を指定し、セルを選択したら、 segue で移動するようにしました。

このような状況で、セルを選択すると、元の UITableView がスクロールしてから、segue が実施される、という状況が生じることがあります。
普通であれば、元の UITableView でスクロールすることはないと思うのですが、私の開発状況では、選択されたセルが表示されている範囲でちょうど一番下になるような感じにスクロールされます。

状況の再現を行おうとして、シンプルなテストケースを作ろうとしたのですが、きちんとした再現が行えませんでした。

ただ、そのテストケースの場合でも、ときどき勝手にスクロールすることが起きる事は確認できました。ちなみに、問題の開発状況では、上記で、Accessory Action ではなく、Selection Segue にして didSelectRowAtIndexPath → peformSegueWithIdentifier を通さなくても、スクロールしてしまいます。

何かヒントでもいただければと思い、質問する次第です。よろしく御願いいたします。